# php insert data into mysql but load options from a (different) table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple form and I input the data into a database, that works fine. Now i would like to load one option from a different table, that also works fine. What doesnt work fine is when I put those 2 things in one. Somehow I am able only to do one of those things, the loading options dont work. Could you help me out here please?

Here is the code, I tried to keep it simple.

```html
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Chyba připojování k databázi. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 
// Escape user inputs for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$nickname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['nickname']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);


 

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, nickname, phone) VALUES ('$name', '$nickname', '$username')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
} else{


    echo "ERROR " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
 <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>

<label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
 <select name="nickname" id="nickname">
<?php
$res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from wp_is_users");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<option><?php echo $row["user_login"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>

 <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Přidat záznam"><br>
```

`

Comment: Looks like you're killing the mysql connection before your second query

Comment: I deleted the link but the options wont load anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
mysqli_close($link);
```

Firstly, you don't need it. Secondly when you fire a POST method it closes the connection and THEN you are tryingthe second query.

Also, open the connection before you check the request method, so the beginning of your file should go like this:

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
```

This way it will work even if the method is get, which is default.

Comment: I deleted the link but the options wont load anyway

Comment: You should also open the connection before you check the type of request.

Comment: I updated the code. You can check with my real connection

Comment: I edited the the answer, check it now. And please delete the comment with your actual connection. Unsafe as can be.

Comment: Always a pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

just don't close your connection on database 
comment this line
//mysqli_close($link);

Comment: I deleted the link but the options wont load anyway

Comment: please provide full error 
and you should but 
`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Chyba připojování k databázi. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}`
in beginning of page before any if and after <?php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You were not submitting form properly. I have added some line of code for proper form submission

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db");
// Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Chyba připojování k databázi. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


// Escape user inputs for security

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {//if form submit button is set
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
        $nickname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['nickname']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);


// attempt insert query execution
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, nickname, phone) VALUES ('$name', '$nickname', '$username')";
        if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        } else {


            echo "ERROR " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

// close connection
       // mysqli_close($link);  skip this code
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>

    <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
    <select name="nickname" id="nickname">
        <?php
        $res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from wp_is_users");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            ?>
            <option><?php echo $row["user_login"]; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Přidat záznam"><br>
```